# Using Rest to trigger remote procedures

Tags: rest

I am working on an application that is primarily concerned with polling data from a third party, then mapping and persisting relevant information to a customer.  It does this on a fixed interval, but the requirements also specify a way to manually fire off the process.  This manual call will only receive a status on the execution of the process, but is not interested in the data created by the process.

I implemented the call using http, but my implementation has been identified as not RESTful.  Having now done the research into what better than means, I completely concur as I was using the URI to define verbs instead of nouns.

Is it possible to make this RESTful?  Is it okay to make a resource that is extremely transient, like this?

> POST /rpc/{process}?param1=....&....

Or should the process itself be considered permanent, but the triggering of as a temporary update?  I doubt this as this is not an idempotent action.

> PUT /rpc/{process}?run=true&param1......

Is there a correct way to handle this and be called RESTful?  If it is not, do I use SOAP or continue to use the simple http structure and live with the fact that it is not RESTful?

Answer (score 0):

Use querystrings for filtering 
POST/PUT depends on what you want your process to do (PUT for idempotent actions, POST for non idempotent actions).

Keep it simple and I do not see any issues the way you have resolved this.